# (Windows 7 virtualbox) Crashes After I Enable 3D Accelation And Change Resolution

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I installed windows 7 on Oracle Virtualbox. I Can't change the resolution. When I try, it shuts down and restarts windows 7. It works when 3D acceleration is off.
(I have guest additions)

Comment: Did you build the Windows 7 machine?  How did you manage to update it ?  (Rhetorical question).  Did you get it from someone else?

Answer (score 1):

Try VirtualBox 6.1.x instead of latest 7.x version:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_6_1

In my experience, 7.x still is rather unstable, especially when it comes to "3D Acceleration" and older Windows versions. Note that version 6.1.x is still maintained.

Comment: Thanks! This worked!

Answer (score 0):

Few months ago I also faced the same issue in virtualbox, after enabling the 3D Accelation it crashes everytime. And then I updated the Vbox to the latest version and it worked. If updating Vbox doesn't fix your issue, I would recommend you to update drivers of your Windows Host machine.